# Putting contiguous items in a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this and don't know how I'd write the query to only retrieve contiguous items.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Id</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to query this table and pull out data that looks like this?

```
Section    Items
1          1-2, 4
2          5, 7-8
```

Where we exclude the items that don't have an Id of 1?

Comment: Did you try a cursor or loop?   Seems like it should be pretty easy that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use CTE and Dense_Rank to achieve this:

```
--setting up data 
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
section int,
number int, 
id int
)

insert into @t
values(1,1,1),
(1,2,1),
(1,3,2),
(1,4,1),
(2,5,1),
(2,6,2),
(2,7,1),
(2,8,1)

--Query
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT SECTION,
       number,
       DR = number - DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY number)
    FROM @t
    WHERE id <> 2
    GROUP BY SECTION,
          number
)
SELECT SECTION,
    STUFF(
          (
             SELECT ', '+CASE
                          WHEN MIN(number) <> MAX(number)
                          THEN CAST(MIN(number) AS VARCHAR(MAX))+'-'+CAST(MAX(number) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                          ELSE CAST(MAX(number) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                       END
             FROM cte
             WHERE SECTION = Results.SECTION
             GROUP BY SECTION,
                       DR FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
          ).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''
       ) AS Items
FROM cte Results
GROUP BY SECTION;
```